# Add a second Range to hiding rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is my formula and it works.

```
Rows("8").Hidden = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Currency").Range("E2").Value <> "No"
```

I want to add a second range("E5") with the same rule
I've tried:

```
Rows("8").Hidden = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Currency").Range("E2,E5").Value <> "No"
Rows("8").Hidden = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Currency").Range("E2","E5").Value <> "No"
Rows("8").Hidden = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Currency").Range("E2"),("E5").Value <> "No"
```

Comment: You will need to test both separately with `And`

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you.Where do I add the and? Sorry - silly question.

Comment: `...Range("E2")<>"No" And ... Range("E5) <> "No"`